# UITextView size for UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview, one of the rows contains a cell that contains a UITextView. I need to know the size of the textview because I need it to fit the cell and return that size in 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' method. Using the NSString method for size only works for labels, not for textviews. What are my options?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the UITextView already have the proper size, or do you need to resize it as well to exactly contain its text? There are no out-of-the-box methods to do that I believe.

If it already has the proper size, you can just get the height from its frame:

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame;
CGSize size = frame.size;
CGFloat = size.height;
```